# Why are there two groups of lifecycle callbacks in lit-element?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, custom-element, lit-element

These are the hooks defined by web component specification:

- connectedCallback
- disconnectedCallback
- adoptedCallback
- attributeChangedCallback

These are defined by lit-element maybe:

- someProperty.hasChanged
- requestUpdate
- performUpdate
- shouldUpdate
- update
- render
- firstUpdated
- updated
- updateComplete

What is the difference between the two groups?

The first group is not enough for developers to use? If it is, why not to add more methods to the specification?

Comment: Any reason you've not accepted answers to any of your last 80+ questions asked?  Have I answered your question adequately?  Would appreciate an acceptance or a follow-up if you're not satisfied, and I'm sure many others who've tried to help you would also.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first group are [lifecycle callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) of [native custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element) of the Web Component standard.

The second group are the [additional lifecycle callbacks](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle) that are added by LitElement via extension.

Native custom elements may be "enough" for some developers, but many will appreciate the commonly needed coordination between properties and rendering provided by LitElement's extensions.